# ORA-00904: "MONTH": invalid identifier

Tags: mysql, oracle

I am trying to fetch the list of all employees who born in the current month.I have stored date like '16-Sep-2017' and whenever I run my code it gives me error ORA-00904: "MONTH": invalid identifier.
Here is my code:

```
SELECT * from employee1 where month(birth_date)=month(now);

SELECT * FROM employee1 WHERE month(bithdate) = MONTH(CURRENTTIME());

SELECT  * FROM employee1
WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(birth_date, '%d-%m-%Y')) = MONTH(NOW());

SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE1 WHERE STR_TO_DATE(BIRTH_DATE,'%d-%m-%y')=MONTH(CURRENT_DATE);

select * from employee1 
where CAST(SUBSTRING(birth_date,'%d-%m-%y')AS unsigned)=MONTH(CURRENT_DATE);

select * from employee1 
where CAST(SUBSTRING(birth_date,'%d-%m-%y')AS varchar2)=MONTH(CURRENT_DATE);

select * from employee1 where to_date('birthdate', 'dd-mon-yyyy')=month(current_date);
```

I have tried all the possibilities but every time I am having an error invalid month identifier

Comment: Why do you have a MySQL tag for an Oracle error? `ORA-00904` is the clue. If you Google just a little bit, you might find the cause: Is `bithdate` (missing an 'r') an actual column name?

Comment: I am using MySQL and i have google a lot but still unable to solve it

Comment: Ok, but I'm not sure how you are using MySQL with an Oracle error number???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The oracle form is extract(element from expression) eg select extract(month from current_date) monthnumber from dual;

Comment: select emp_name,birth_date from employee1 where extract(month from birth_date)=extract(month from current_date);
i have tried this code and it works.

Comment: weirdly enough, in the oracle documentation it tells you to use month(date) and year(date) instead, which doesn't work